# loading a sub menu in layout page using Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a layout page that can render all my views.
The **layout contains 7 links (tabs)**

that when user clicks on them **load a partial view for dynamic menu.**

**Layout**

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
         //   ButtonClick(1);
         function ButtonClick(x) {
             $.ajax({
                 type: "POST",
                 cache: false,
                 url: "MenuItem/Menu",
                 data: { MenuId: x },
                 dataType: "html",
                 async: true,
                 success: function (data) {
                     $("#menuContent").html(data);
                     //   alert('success');
                 }
             });
             return false;
         }

       </script>
</head>


<a class="Tab" href="~/Tab1/Index"> ble
    <img src="~/Content/images/b2.png" id="b2" onclick="return ButtonClick(2);">
</a> 
  <div id="menuContent"></div>      .... etc
```

and when i *clicks on the any* item in the sub menu -> it loads the page and redirect me to the right view But **Then the sub menu disappeared after** !! and when i try to save the last button clicked on a session variable. it doesn't work well in case the user clicked on (a link) to show more details info and have a different sub menu.
The sub menu is different for all the tabs.

how can i fix that ?

**Edit**
I think i didn't explain my problem well, the thing is button click function is working fine with me when clicking the tabs. but i want the (links inside the view)& the links inside the sub menu to render this function ButtonClick(x) to load the partial view for menu again? how can i do that?
**Thanks in advance.**

Comment: Maybe I am wrong, but could it be that the anchor is firing, and therefore rendering a new menuContent?

Comment: please see my problem description in edit section. Thanks

Comment: Does your partial views inherit a different layout page than your main layout which has the sub menu defined?

Comment: No, the same main layout.